# mysql syntax to return latest total of multiple lines

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe2

That may be the worst title I've ever written!

I have a table with entries similar to this:

```
1 ¦ ABC1 ¦ 21
2 ¦ DEF2 ¦ 43
3 ¦ DEF2 ¦ 44
4 ¦ XYZ9 ¦ 18
5 ¦ ABC1 ¦ 19
```

I'm trying to phrase a statement in MySQL that would return just:

```
ABC1 ¦ 19
XYZ9 ¦ 18
DEF2 ¦ 44
```

...so the latest individual total for each unique code. I'm new to the language and can't crack the syntax!

Hopefully that makes sense but please feel free to ask any clarifying questions (of course!).

Many thanks,

Jon

Comment: Perhaps you can make separate "is-visible" boolean column and use server-side triggers to keep it up to date ? Or you can make a special derived table, that would only list visible rows for your table, just (<row-id> and <col2>) table. That would be even better. or use Join like Joe suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming table with column `id`, `name`, `count`

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM <tablename> GROUP BY name)
```

Comment: Thanks Salil, this worked perfectly for me. Not to say the other answers wouldn't work but this one was first and successful.

Comment: Dunno how MySQL optimizer works here, but usually "IN" makes worse code than "join". If MySQL would fail to mutate this code into join it might end with poor performance (scale badly when table would grow in both dimensions)

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick in mysql for exactly this:

```
select code, num
from (select * from mytable
      order by id desc) x
group by code;
```

While this is not a valid query on other RDBMSs, in mysql a group by without aggregating the other columns returns the *first* row encountered (hence the inner order by to get the latest rows sorted first).

Unlike traditional queries using complicated sub queries, this will perform very well.

Comment: This also has sub-query. I can't see much difference from Joe's answer

Comment: @Arioch There's a massive difference to joes answer. His inner query to calc th maxes is a full pass over the table, then the outer one does another full pass, plus there's a join without index to the temporary table from the inner result (temporary results can't have indexes) so each row will require z full pass over the temp table. My query is way faster because it does only **one.** pass over the table to order by, then another pass over that result: I avoid one full pass and importantly I have no join. My query would out-perform joes by orders of magnitude.

Comment: the inner query should just use some compound index and only take max element for each text value :-)

Comment: "plus there's a join without index to the temporary table from the inner result" oh, my... does mySQL really allocate temporary table there ??? really??? oh my...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select * 
from   <table> t
join   (
        select max(col1) as col1 ,col2
        from   <table>
        group by col2)a
on      t.col1=a.col1
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48111/2)